# How to install software on 2 in 1 Windows 8 computer

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I'm looking at buying a 2 in 1 computer, which is a laptop with a dockable screen. When the screen is undocked it becomes a tablet and the keyboard isn't used.

This device has 2 hard drives, a 32GB SSD built into the 'tablet' and a 500gb HDD built into the keyboard.

I understand that I am only able to access the 500GB hard drive when the tablet is docked, but my question is can software be installed onto the 500GB hard drive (such as Visual Studio 2012 premium)?

Comment: If it depends on the software and computer, then I'm looking to install Visual Studio 2012 and Tortoise SVN onto an Asus Transformer T200TA

Comment: Can you provide us with the details of the laptop you are planning to purchase? A link to the product page will do where the specs are given in details.

Comment: This is the computer - http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/laptops-netbooks/ipad-tablets-and-ereaders/tablets/asus-transformer-book-t200ta-11-6-2-in-1-32-gb-500-gb-blue-10107399-pdt.html (and if this links dies, Google/Bing `T200TA 11.6" Z3775`) @Ayan

Answer (score 2):

You can install the software anywhere (if you go through the custom option in most setup programs).

However you wont be able to use the app if the drive isn't attached, this seems obvious...but if the application added anything to startup then you might see issues, so be aware.

In your case Visual Studio should be fine.

Comment: To elaborate: When installing a program, MOST will show the drive path it is being installed to (C:\Programs\MyDaftQuestionsProgramToBeInstalled) - You just change that path to the new location on the 500GB HDD you'd like to install to.